# Python exception for handling invalid argument types

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, exception

**Greetings**

One small problem that anyone have to tackle with in Python is handling invalid argument types ( without an automatic static type checking tool like
[***Mypy***](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) )

One of the best methods for handling the invalid argument is raising an exception which would easily inform the code client with the required steps to fix, ( I.E ):

> "Expected argument type passed for the parameter ( im_a_parameter ): ( int ) | Not: ( str )"

in this case, raising a [***ValueError***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) would get the job done.
While attending this method, as my project was growing larger, I found out that repeating this idiom would deny the [***DRY principle***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so I rolled up my sleeves, and came up with a fixture:

**unexpected_argument_type.py**

```
"""
# The holder module for the UnexpectedArgumentTypeError exception class
"""



class UnexpectedArgumentTypeError(ValueError):
    def __init__(self, parameter: str, expected_argument_types: object | list[object]) -> None:
        """
        # Args:
            
            1. ( parameter ): The expected parameter of the current function signature.

            2. ( expected_argument_types ): The types that were expected to be passed to the function parameter.
        """

        self.passed_argument = parameter
        self.passed_argument_type = parameter
        self.expected_argument_types = expected_argument_types

        self._generate_error_message()
        super().__init__(self._error_message)

    def _generate_error_message(self):
        if isinstance(self.expected_argument_type, object) and not self._arguments_are_list:
            self._error_message = (
                f"Expected argument type passed for the parameter \
( {self.passed_argument} ): ( {self.expected_argument_type} ) | Not ( {self.passed_argument_type} )."
            )
            return 

        if isinstance(self.expected_argument_type, list):
            expected_argument_types_str = ', '.join(self.expected_argument_type)
            self._error_message = (
                f"Expected argument type passed for the parameter \
( {self.passed_argument} ): ( {expected_argument_types_str} ) | Not ( {self.passed_argument_type} )"
            )

    @property
    def passed_argument_type(self):
        return self._passed_argument_type
    
    @passed_argument_type.setter
    def passed_argument_type(self, argument_type):
        self._passed_argument_type = type(argument_type).__name__

    @property
    def expected_argument_types(self):
        return self._expected_argument_type
    
    @expected_argument_types.setter
    def expected_argument_type(self, arguments):
        if not isinstance(arguments, (list, object)):
            raise ValueError("The ( expected_argument_type ) argument must be object| e.x: ( str, tuple... )")
        
        if isinstance(arguments, list):
            self._arguments_are_list = True
            arguments = [str(argument) for argument in arguments]

        if isinstance(arguments, object) and not self._arguments_are_list:
            arguments = arguments.__name__

        self._expected_argument_type = arguments
```

After all of this, one question remains:

> Does handling this problem worth the complexity that this piece of code adds?
> ( Writing unit tests, maintaining documentations ).

Comment: Missing a lot of code.  What is in `coding`, `coding/database`, and `coding/database/exceptions`?  How is this fixture used?  This is currently incomplete, so off-topic until the additional code is added.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## missing review context

This submission of a utility class is off-topic, as it
does not offer any examples of caller code
that relies on the utility.
We can't see how caller's life is made better by
existence of the utility,
there's no "with" vs "without" contrast offered.

## comparison with the competition

### mypy

> ... handling invalid argument types ( without an automatic static type checking tool like Mypy )

There exist reasons why a project may be reluctant to
adopt `mypy` or may choose to reject such linters.
But this submission does not mention any of those reasons,
so we cannot evaluate its fitness for purpose.
In short, we don't know the intended use case.

### beartype

Sometimes I *do* want strict runtime checking.
I have been pretty happy with
[@beartype](https://pypi.org/project/beartype) decorators.

```
>>> from beartype import beartype
>>> 
>>> @beartype
... def increment(n: int) -> int:
...     return n + 1
... 
>>> 
>>> increment(2)
3
>>> increment(2.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<@beartype(__main__.increment) at 0x1057c4360>", line 28, in increment
beartype.roar.BeartypeCallHintParamViolation: Function __main__.increment() parameter n=2.0 violates type hint <class 'int'>, as float 2.0 not instance of int.
```

This submission makes no attempt to explain how
it offers a solution competitive with `mypy` or `@beartype`.

> Is handling this problem worth the complexity that this piece of code adds?

No.

Comment: In rev 3 we see unreviewed code like `module_paths.append(...)`. I literally could not read that, I didn't know what it meant, and went looking for a `sys.module_paths` which of course doesn't exist. Eventually I noticed the deceptive import alias that turned familiar `sys.path` into something new but not improved. Prefer to use the bash command `$ env PYTHONPATH=.:database:database/exceptions python foo.py` so `sys.path` is set up properly from the get go, even during interpreter initialization. // **Occasionally** we prefer to `import` inside a `def`, due to time expense or error. Not here.